# grammar files .g compatibility frome Antlr 2.7 to 4?

Tags: antlr, compatibility, antlr4, antlr3, backwards-compatibility

**The situation:** We are porting our old simulation platform for *math/physics/CS* popularization [MobiNet](http://mobinet.imag.fr/index.en.html) from **C++** to online **JS**.
At that time the **MobiNet** language was dealt using **Antlr 2.7.3**.

- Can we expect our `calc.g` to directly work in **Antlr4**? (I'm afraid by the suffix renamed **.g4**).
- If not direct, how hard will it be to upgrade?
- If it will be difficult, is there any way to ease the job (e.g. with an older **Antlr** version, as long as the **JS** target works) ?

**Note:** We have no energy for re-design, just porting, and already many aspects to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1:
As Lex also pointed out, no, the original grammar won't work.

Q2:
Upgrading from *ANTLR 2* to *ANTLR 4*  can be a tedious task depending on lots of small details. In your `calc.g`, the parser rules do not seem to be so complex, but you have to know that the concepts of the parsing technology changed from *ANTLR 2* to *ANTLR 3* (`LL(k)` to `LL(*)`, see details [here](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2687279)) and also from *ANTLR 3* to *ANTLR 4* (`LL(*)` to `AdaptiveLL(*)`, details [here](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1900596)). If you use the AST generation, it has changed a lot too. 
Also, you'll have to change the target from C++ and rewrite the actions anyway.

Q3:
Upgrading from *ANTLR 2* to *ANTLR 3* is probably easier and might solve your migration issue. But it is another question if it's really worth spending time on upgrading to *ANTLR 3* (and then, maybe, upgrade to another version later), or spending some (probably more) time on upgrading  directly to *ANTLR 4*.

Comment: argh, I couldn't answer long and formatted here. -> I "auto-answer" below.

Comment: ... and the below finally landed on above. :-/

Comment: - Migrating 2 to 3: ok, I didn't saw the link in your link at first reading.  

- Auto-converter: there was one, good : but too bad it's now a 404. :-/

Comment: For the curious: the migration tool for ANTLR 2 to ANTLR 3 is still available at http://www.antlr3.org/download/v2v3-0.2.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys !

- changing target is the easy part (we know how to map the variables of our old C++ engine to our new JS engine).
- upgrading the grammar might be out of reach for our poor young engineer with already so  many aspects to learn and deal with, so I'll have to prefetch and arbitrate about what to do to ease his job.
- migration is more C++ to JS, version of Antlr is just a side effect of it: versions have changed, plus JS was not even supported. If migration is way more easy with Antlr3 this is a serious option, but is support of JS correctly working in v3 ? (forums and webpages are kind of contradictory here).
- reading the 2 links you provided, I see many enhancements and new possibilities, but nothing clear about what no longer work. Or do you mean that at least for 3 to 4, the syntax has changed totally ?
- just in case: nobody wrote a .g to .g4 translator ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. You will have to upgrade the grammar file manually.